# How to setup ode functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

For me it is not clear how to use ode45 for matlab. I have a vector u.
Does anybody know what this error is?

```
function [v, t, d] x =deep(l)
x = max(u(:,1));
v = u;
t = 1;
d = 1;
```

```
options = odeset('Events', @deep)
```

But when i call ode45 with

```
ode45(@odefun, [0 85], [0 0], options)
```

i get this error:

```
Error in odeevents (line 28)
  eventValue = feval(eventFcn,t0,y0,eventArgs{:});
Error in ode45 (line 148)
  odeevents(FcnHandlesUsed,odeFcn,t0,y0,options,varargin);
```

Comment: That error is not complete, can you show us teh full error?

Answer (score 1):

There are some inconsistencies in your text and code.

1. "I have a vector u":

But your function definition is:

```
function [v, t, d] x =deep(l)
x = max(u(:,1));
v = u;
t = 1;
d = 1;
```

Where is your vector `u` in the function definition?

The `ode45` function integrates functions of the type:

y' = f(t,y)

The function you should pass to ode45 should have two arguments and should return one output:

- Input `t`, the independent parameter. The function is integrated between the values `t=t0` and `t=tf`;
- Input `y`, the vector of dependent variables.
- Output `dy`, a vector with the derivative of the dependent variables.

2. When you call the `ode45` function:

   ode45(@odefun, [0 85], [0 0], options)

You have not defined `odefun` anywhere, MATLAB should throw an error there.

You have to change the `deep` function and the `ode45` call to make it work:

```
dy = deep(t,y)
dy = ? <- define it
```

And call it:

```
ode45(@deep,tspan,y0)
```

Comment: I think i have forgotten the put the vector in it. This function is given. And i have to change the function that ode45 stop to calculate after the first low. ```
function x=deep(l)

[t, u]=ode45(@b, [0 91], [0 0 l]);
x = max(u(:,1));
```
But for me ist not clear how i should change that function that after the first low, the calculate, stop.